# Is there a way through which I can embed external HTML page as a component at run time in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

We know that we can use pages or components in ionic. These pages and components contain .html files, which have html markup. When we build the app, all these files are bundled into the app.

My question is whether we can use or embed external .html files and act on that .html file.

For example: if we have a login page which contains username and password fields and submit button. We have already defined css for this page. There is a requirement for my project to embed external .html file and use it as login page. It may have a different css.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that you have html tags in JSON response for example and you want to add them to ionic just do :

```
<div [innerHTML]="your-JSON-response-Html"></div>
```